# Remove part of String that is inside a pair of hashes

Tags: java, regex

I would like to remove a part of a `String` surrounded by `#`'s, like so:

```
String s = "#thispartneedstogo#anythingelsecanremain"
//remove "#thispartneedstogo#"
s = "anythingelsecanremain"
```

I tried to do this using this code:

```
String stripped = content.replaceAll("#.*?#", "").replace("\n", "");
```

However, it did not give me the expected result.

Note, I would like a universal answer which would detect and delete this so called 'pattern', i.e. in a `String` like `"#remove#keep#remove#"` where only `"keep"` remains, if possible.

Comment: What result did it give you, and what exactly was unexpected about it?

Comment: I won't swear for the behavior in java, but typically `.*` is greedy, hence it would match everything between the outer-most '#' and the replaceAll result would be an empty string.  I would expect to use the pattern `"#[^#]*#"` to yield the desired results.

Comment: Your code is OK. If your executed code was missing the question mark, then the result would be a blank string, because `.*` is greedy

Comment: "*it did not give me the expected result.*" what results you get and what did you expect?

Comment: @David Your solution actually solved the problem. If you'd post an answer, I'd gladly accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'*' in regular expressions is, generally speaking, greedy, meaning that it will consume all available matches.  In your case it will match from the first '#' to the last '#', including the '#'s in the middle.

Change your regular expression to the more specific:

```
"#[^#]*#"
```

to avoid matching the intervening '#'

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually does work the way you intended:

```
String s = "#remove#keep#remove#";
String stripped = s.replaceAll("#.*?#", "");
System.out.println(stripped);  // keep
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for extracting the final bit;

```
String ss[] = s.split("#");
String desiredStr = ss[ss.length-1];
```

Or you can use String tokenizer to tokenize the input string and get all the parameters with # free.

You probably needed to do this with the replaceAll method:

```
String ss = s.replaceAll(replace_what, replace_with_what);
```

So you needed,
    String ss = s.replaceAll("#",""); // Someone surely has corrected this in the answer lists :)

If you want to detect a specific word like "keep" in "#remove#keep#remove#", best way is to do the following:

```
// String s = "#thispartneedstogo#anythingelsecanremain";
String s = "#remove#keep#remove#";

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.split("#"));

// Suppose you want to check if something specific is in the list, but not
// necessarily how many times i.e. if there are duplicates:

// Obviously, parameterise remove with something like string ps = "remove";
if (list.contains("remove")){
    System.out.println("Found remove");
}
```

Just a bit about regexp-based replacements:

I personally hate regexp as it is the most horrendous and confusing thing ever invented in the programming language world (finished ranting!). However, the following should give you more of a generalised replacement (i.e. if you want only alphabetic characters in your final String):

```
s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]+",""); // Replaces anything that is not an alph
```

Comment: Thanks for your input - but what I wanted was something like Java has with comments, i.e. `/* ... */`. Thanks though =)

Answer (score -3):

make the part u want to replace in separate variable

```
 String a = "#thispartneedstogo#";
    String s = "anythingelsecanremain";

    s = s+a;
// to replace
    System.out.println(s.replace("#thispartneedstogo#");
// to add
    System.out.println(a.concat(s));
```

Comment: This fails to answer the more general question of how to remove _any_ content that appears between the hashes.  For example, how do you get the `#stuffToDelete#` into `a`?